# HttpMessageNotReadableException : Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I send my object (json) from (angular5) to server spring (java) my object have some attributes as objects too. (many to one)

```
class A{

String name;
ClassB classB;
}
```

the schema of database the

```
table A
________
id : 1
name : Med
fk_b : 2
```

I need to update my object in order to change the value of  to become empty [ in this case ClassB (json) will be empty ] ===> the case that cause the problem

```
  table A
    ________
    id : 1
    name : Med
    fk_b :
```

or the send a filled object (this works fine)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? what json works and what doesn't? Please provide minimal example along with the code.

Comment: I should send object with null value not with " "